# IBExpert 2021.7.8.1 - Firebird 2.5 database compare stored procedure domain names commented out

Tags: firebird, ibexpert

I have IBExpert 2021.7.8.1 and Firebird 2.5

When I perform a database compare on stored procedures, my input and output parameters domain names are removed and replaced with the variable representative. On most occasions the domain is commented out.

Here's a snippet of what the update script looks like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE WIP_CURRENT_MONTH_PROCEDURE(
  IP_SELECTEDYEAR /* SMALLINT_DOMAIN */ SMALLINT,
  IP_SELECTEDMONTH /* SMALLINT_DOMAIN */ SMALLINT,
  IP_MONTHSDIFFERENCE /* INTEGER_DOMAIN */ INTEGER,
  IP_MAX_MONTHS_REMOVED /* INTEGER_DOMAIN */ INTEGER,
  IP_EOM_RUN SMALLINT)
RETURNS (
  OP_CONTRACTVALUE /* MONETRY_DOMAIN */ NUMERIC(15,2),
  OP_ESTIMATED_COSTS /* MONETRY_DOMAIN */ NUMERIC(15,2),
  OP_MECHANICAL_VX_2 /* MONETRY_DOMAIN */ NUMERIC(15,2),
```

Here's a snippet of what the update script should look like:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE WIP_CURRENT_MONTH_PROCEDURE(
  IP_SELECTEDYEAR SMALLINT_DOMAIN,
  IP_SELECTEDMONTH SMALLINT_DOMAIN,
  IP_MONTHSDIFFERENCE INTEGER_DOMAIN,
  IP_MAX_MONTHS_REMOVED INTEGER_DOMAIN,
  IP_EOM_RUN SMALLINT_DOMAIN)
RETURNS (
  OP_CONTRACTVALUE MONETRY_DOMAIN,
  OP_ESTIMATED_COSTS MONETRY_DOMAIN,
  OP_MECHANICAL_VX_2 MONETRY_DOMAIN
```

Any ideas why this occurs for stored procedures?

Comment: Sounds like IBExpert specific behaviour to me.

Comment: For example `isql -ex` will produce DDL using the domain names. Given IBExpert shows it in comments, I guess this is intentional behaviour, and there probably is a configuration option for it (but I have never used IBExpert, so I'm not sure about that), looking at https://www.ibexpert.net/ibe/pmwiki.php?n=Doc.DatabaseRegistrationInfo, it might be under Additional > Extract Metadata of the database properties.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel. Thanks for the reply.  The only option in IBExpert|Additional|Extract Metadata is "Use UPDATE instead of DESCRIBE when extracting object descriptions."

Comment: At least in IBE's "extract metadata" window it is called "decode domains". Do you have similar options in the database comparer? if not, try doing metadata extraction without it and let's hope the setting would would persist somewhere and get used by database comparer.  https://i.imgur.com/iRMYiIy.png